# Code doesn't work after securing it

Tags: php, mysql

As school project, I have to design a site( with all functionality ( html & php)). I'm almost done with it except that I'm stuck on a little headache. I'm trying to secure my site to prevent msql injection. I've used the statement `mysql_real_escape_string()` and it works fine on the other pages, except on this one. When i use the `mysql_real_escape_string` on the variables `$email` and `$firstname`, the page returns with no result. But then I remove the `mysql_real_escape_string()`, the code works perfectly. The job of this code is to get the forgotten password of the user.  What am I doing wrong here that the variables stops working when I protect them?
(By the way, I apologize for being a noob in php. Any help is gladly welcomed)

```
<?php
error_reporting(0);

if($_POST['submit']=='Send')
{
$db_host="localhost";  
$db_uname="";    
$db_pass=""; 
$db_name="";
mysql_connect($db_host,$db_uname,$db_pass) or die(mysql_error);
mysql_select_db($db_name);
$email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['emailadress']);
$firstname=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['First_name']);

$query="SELECT customer.email_client, customer.first_name FROM customer WHERE       email_client='$email' AND first_name='$firstname'";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die(error);

if(mysql_num_rows($result)){
$code= md5(uniqid(rand(), true));
$message="Please use the following link with the given activation code from below to       begin the validation process."."\n".
"This is the link--> http://regina.roelgonzalez.tk/pages_directory    /confirmationforum.php".
 "\n". "The activation code is: ".$code;
if (isset($_REQUEST['emailadress'])){
$_sender='www.postmasterSPapiesOnlineShopping.com';
mail($email, "Activation code", $message ,"From:" . $_sender);
$insertinto="UPDATE customer SET activation_code = '$code' WHERE first_name = '$firstname' AND email_client='$email'";
mysql_query($insertinto) or die(error);

?>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
alert("Please check your email for the confirmation code");
window.location = "confirmationforum.php";
</script>
<?php

}
}
else{
?>
<script type="text/javascript"> alert
("Either given informaion is wrong, or data does not appear in our database");
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.location = "forgottenforum.php";
</script> 
<?php

 }
 mysql_close($con);
 }
?>
```

Comment: I hope they aren't teaching you to use `mysql_*` functions.

Comment: Maybe you've used `adress` instead of `address`?

Comment: Apart from a ton of errors, let's see the HTML form of this.

Comment: `die(mysql_error());` and not `die(error);`

Comment: You will have to spend just as much time unlearning the things this class is teaching.